# Why network-first strategy is slower than no service worker?

Tags: service-worker, workbox

While benchmarking performance of service worker with workbox, we found an interesting phenomena.

When service worker is applied, network-first strategy of workbox takes about 30 ms slower than no service worker networking. Then, we tried to skip workbox and implement network-first strategy manually, it is about 20ms slower.

My guess is that, if service worker kicks in, all request has to be handled by javascript code. It is the execution of JavaScript code that make the networking slower.

Then, I checked cache-first strategy, it turns out that fetching content from cache-storage is slower than fetching content from disk-cache(http cache) without service worker.

So, in my understanding, even though service worker offers us more control on caching, it is not guaranteed to be faster in caching, right?

Answer (score 6):

There is a cost associated with starting up a service worker that was not previously running. This could be on the order of tens of milliseconds, depending on the device. Once that service worker starts up, if it doesn't handle your navigation requests (which are almost certainly the first request that a service worker would receive) by going against the cache, then it's likely you'll end up with worse performance than if there were no service worker present at all.

If you are going against the cache, then having a service worker present should offer roughly the same performance vs. looking things up against the HTTP browser cache once it's actually running, but there is the same startup cost that needs to be taking into account first.

The real performance benefits of using a service worker come from handling navigation requests for HTML in a cache-first manner, which is not something you could traditionally do with HTTP caching.

You can read more about these tradeoffs and best practices in 
"[High-performance service worker loading](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/high-performance-loading)".